# Disable the numbering of algorithms

Tags: numbering, algorithms

My problem is that I do not know how to disable the numbering for algorithms. I have created an algoritm and its number is "Algorithm 1", but I want to have "Algorithm".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic} 
% Hide endif .etc

\usepackage{algorithm}

\algsetup{indent=2em} 
% Default 1 em

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hspace{2em}// #1} 
% Change to C-style comments, though still ugly

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{MyAlgorithm} \label{alg:MyAlgorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    % Default no line numbering



    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how do you create the caption? Give a complete example

Comment: @Herbert - added

Answer (score 15, accepted):

posting working examples would be a nice idea ... ;-)
Now only page references make sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{algorithm,caption}
\algsetup{indent=2em} 
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hspace{2em}// #1} 

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption*{MyAlgorithm} \label{alg:MyAlgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\item foo
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

see algorithm on Page~\pageref{alg:MyAlgorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A-HA, it works. thx

Comment: Actually I didn't know we have to add caption package before using *

Comment: What is your code doing?  what is the part that disables numbering??

Comment: @colinfang  how does this disable numbering?

Answer (score 10):

Setting the counter to nothing also works fine

```
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
```

Comment: Werner's answer gives some context about \thealgorithm macro in case anyone is looking for why this works

Answer (score 8):

The algorithm name and number are set as a combination. In general this is inside the "float macro" called `\fnum@<float>`. In the case of [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) we see this definition for `\fnum@algorithm`:

```
> \fnum@algorithm=macro:
->\fname@algorithm {} \thealgorithm .
```

We can redefine this to only use `\fname@algorithm` (and therefore drop `\thealgorithm` - the algorithm numbering):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{MyAlgorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State An item
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

A similar interface/option is provided using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{algnonumber}{Algorithm}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=algnonumber}
```