# Disable Algorithm Numbering

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/disable-the-numbering-of-algorithms) but I still disable the numbering of algorithms.

I have the following code:

```
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{\textsc{FizzBuzz}}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \FOR{$i \Leftarrow 1 \ldots 100$}
                \IF{$i$ \emph{mod} $3 = 0 \wedge i$ \emph{mod} $5 = 0$}
                    \item \textsc{Print}(``FizzBuzz")
                \ELSIF{$i$ \emph{mod} $3 = 0$}
                    \item \textsc{Print}(``Fizz")
                \ELSIF{$i$ \emph{mod} $5 = 0$}
                    \item \textsc{Print}(``Buzz")
                \ELSE
                    \item \textsc{Print}($i$)
                \ENDIF
            \ENDFOR
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

It renders the following:

[image: Algorithm Rendering]

I want to get rid of the part that says `Algorithm 1`. The answer to the question referenced above basically said to change `\caption{\textsc{FizzBuzz}}` to `\caption*{\textsc{FizzBuzz}}`, but when I do that the following is rendered:

[image: Algorithm Rendering (No Caption)]

[This](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode#Algorithm_numbering) offers different algorithm numbering, but I want to disable numbering altogether and keep my caption. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, then the starred variant of `\caption` becomes available. The reason a star shows up in the output now is due to a specific implementation of starred commands in LaTeX.

By the way, the `caption` package will also allow you to customize the format of captions, and you won't need `\textsc` every time then.