# Do not want to display Algorithm number

Tags: algorithms

I don't want to display any number with Algorithm. like Algorithm 1.
I have typed

```
\begin{algorithm}

\label{euclid}

\caption{\textbf{Deep Network}}

\begin{algorithmic}[]
---------------------
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}
```

In output it display Algorithm 1, whereas I do not want the number 1 to be displayed.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Disable the numbering of algorithms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18325/5764)

Comment: Please add a MWE.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your problem.

[image: algorithms]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\hskip-.2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\label{euclid}

\caption{\textbf{Deep Network}}

\begin{algorithmic}[]
\STATE Test
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```